# cannot find symbol textView AndroidStudio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, compiler-errors, textview

I am trying to **Pass Data** from **One Activity** to **Another Activity** in that when when I am writing code to get data in Text View then Showing an error to **textView** Can Anyone Tell me how resolve this error. I am pasting my code Here Please Check and Tell me. **Error At Line Number 12, 14 and 16.** at starting **"textView"**

**Error Compiler Showing is  :**

error: cannot find symbol textView.setText(NameRecive);

symbol:   variable textView

location: class barcode_genrator

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_barcode_genrator);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String NameRecive = intent.getStringExtra(activity_DataEntry.NAME_TO_SEND);
    String SurnameRecive = intent.getStringExtra(activity_DataEntry.SURNAME_TO_SEND);
    String NumberRecive = intent.getStringExtra(activity_DataEntry.NUMBER_TO_SEND);

    TextView name = findViewById(R.id.FN);
    textView.setText(NameRecive);
    TextView surname = findViewById(R.id.LN);
    textView.setText(SurnameRecive);
    TextView number = findViewById(R.id.MN);
    textView.setText(NumberRecive);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The names of the variables you declared are `name`, `surname` and `number`, respectively, not `textView`:

```java
TextView name = findViewById(R.id.FN);
name.setText(NameRecive); // Here
TextView surname = findViewById(R.id.LN);
surname.setText(SurnameRecive); // And here
TextView number = findViewById(R.id.MN);
number.setText(NumberRecive); // And here
```

Answer (score 0):

Like @Mureinik said, you don't have the **textView** variable, only **name**, **surname**, and **number**.
I don't have enough reputations to add a comment to his answer.